# Without realizing the time it would take to complete, I issued the command sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb . What happens if I kill the process?

Tags: terminal, mac, database

Will killing the process cause problems if I shutdown and reboot immediately after doing it? I am running OS 11.2.3 (Big Sur) on Mac Mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It just runs `find` command in the background to collect all file names and then it creates file name database from it. In any case you can simply rebuild the database by running

```
sudo rm -r /var/db/locate.database
```

and then

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

in order to use `locate` command.